# AWS - Creating resources in a multi-account environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I just created a new AWS account using Terraform aws_organizations_account module. What I am now trying to do is to create ressources into that new account. I guess I would need the account_id of the new AWS account to do that so I stored it into a new output variable but after that I have no idea how can I create a aws_s3_bucket for example

**provider.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_organizations_account" "account" {
  name      = "tmp"
  email     = "first.last+tmp@company.com"
  role_name = "myOrganizationRole"
  parent_id = "xxxxx"
}
 
## what I am trying to create inside that tmp account
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {}
```

**outputs.tf**

```
output "account_id" {
  value       = aws_organizations_account.account.id
  sensitive   = true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this the way you want. You need entire, **account creation pipeline** for that. Roughly in the pipeline you would have two main stages:

1. Create your AWS Org and member accounts.
2. **Assume role** from the member accounts, and run your TF code for these accounts to create resources.

There are many ways of doing this, and also there are many resources on this topic. Some of them are:

- [How to Build an AWS Multi-Account Strategy with Centralized Identity Management](https://codeburst.io/how-to-build-an-aws-multi-account-strategy-with-centralized-identity-management-921e5461544)
- [Setting up an AWS organization from scratch with Terraform](https://tbekas.dev/posts/setting-up-an-aws-organization-from-scratch-with-terraform)
- [Terraform on AWS: Multi-Account Setup and Other Advanced Tips](https://thenewstack.io/terraform-on-aws-multi-account-setup-and-other-advanced-tips/)

Apart from those, there is also [AWS Control Tower](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/controltower/latest/userguide/what-is-control-tower.html), which can be helpful in setting up initial multi-account infrastructure.